# Can't truncate MySQL table, while being able to delete all the records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, constraints, sql-delete, truncate

I'm a very beginner to relations, so this may sound dumb. But, what is the difference (in MySQL) between truncating a table and removing all the records ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206090/1469208) answer says only about performance)?

I was playing (in phpMyAdmin) with one of my test tables, to check, how can I reset `auto_increment` value of table and run into situation, where I was able to delete all the records:

```
DELETE from managers;
```

But when I tried to truncate this table (`TRUNCATE managers`), I've got warning: `Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (probes, CONSTRAINT probes_ibfk_4 FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES managers (id));`.

I had to "reset" the `auto_increment` value with `ALTER TABLE managers AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`.

Isn't that something odd? Up until now, I thought, that `TRUNCATE` = `DELETE from managers` (in terms of checking and effects, because performance can be different, but this is not the key here).

How can constraint warning pop on `TRUNCATE` but not on "delete all"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452760/truncate-foreign-key-constrained-table maybe? Your table references itself via foreign key...

Comment: Where do you see, that my table references itself? There is no such reference in either database schema or constraint keys. I must be missing something.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) references managers (id)`

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)` references `managers` table (`id` column), but this (`manager_id` column) is a column from _different_ table. So, it does not reference itself. MySQL (phpMyAdmin) error message may be a little bit misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

truncate resets auto_increment after deleting all rows. so it's not the same as deleting all rows with DELETE command.

from [mysql reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/truncate-table.html):

> Although TRUNCATE TABLE is similar to DELETE, it is classified as a
> DDL statement rather than a DML statement. It differs from DELETE in
> the following ways:
>
> Truncate operations drop and re-create the table, which is much faster
> than deleting rows one by one, particularly for large tables.
>
> Truncate operations cause an implicit commit, and so cannot be rolled
> back. See Section 13.3.3, “Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit”.
>
> Truncation operations cannot be performed if the session holds an
> active table lock.
>
> TRUNCATE TABLE fails for an InnoDB table or NDB table if there are any
> FOREIGN KEY constraints from other tables that reference the table.
> Foreign key constraints between columns of the same table are
> permitted.
>
> Truncation operations do not return a meaningful value for the number
> of deleted rows. The usual result is “0 rows affected,” which should
> be interpreted as “no information.”
>
> As long as the table format file tbl_name.frm is valid, the table can
> be re-created as an empty table with TRUNCATE TABLE, even if the data
> or index files have become corrupted.
>
> Any AUTO_INCREMENT value is reset to its start value. This is true
> even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence
> values.
>
> When used with partitioned tables, TRUNCATE TABLE preserves the
> partitioning; that is, the data and index files are dropped and
> re-created, while the partition definitions (.par) file is unaffected.
>
> The TRUNCATE TABLE statement does not invoke ON DELETE triggers.

Comment: I have managed to reset `auto_increment` with `ALTER TABLE managers AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;`, so your direct answer may be misleading (the fact, that `TRUNCATE` resets `auto_increment` has nothing to do, as I did the same). However, text cited by you does give me an idea, what is going on, so I'm accepting your answer. Thank you.

Comment: The link is dead-like. It points to a page that is redirected to MySQL 8.0 and has no references to MySQL 5.0.3 (which behaves in a totally different way from the way provided answer states).

Comment: Fixed the link.